# What's the right way to make a left to right join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data from my database but I'm having a problem getting my data this way

```
|42|127-1|COMPANY LTDA|ORLANDO |MIT|91919191|Address 1
|42|127-1|COMPANY LTDA|ORLANDO |MIT|92929292|Address 2
```

I do two `LEFT JOIN` to get the address and phone from a client.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT cl.*,phone.c_phone_client,address.c_address_client
FROM  c_client AS cl 
  LEFT JOIN c_client_phone_fk AS phone ON phone.c_id_client = cl.c_id_client
  LEFT JOIN c_client_address_fk AS address ON phone.c_id_client = cl.c_id_client
 WHERE cl.c_id_client='127-1' 
 GROUP BY phone.c_phone_client,address.c_address_client
 ORDER BY address.c_address_client
```

With this query I'm getting this result:

```
|42|127-1|COMPANY LTDA|ORLANDO|MIT|91919191|Address 1
|42|127-1|COMPANY LTDA|ORLANDO|MIT|92929292|Address 1
|42|127-1|COMPANY LTDA|ORLANDO|MIT|91919191|Address 2
|42|127-1|COMPANY LTDA|ORLANDO|MIT|92929292|Address 2
```

How can I fix my query?

Comment: Check your second join condition. _...and if this is a new database you are designing, fk suffixes are typically for foreign key constraints or indexes for such constraints, not tables._

Comment: @Uueerdo change the fiel and still getting the same result :/

Comment: Ah, your join typo(?) distracted me. Your issue is that address and phone are unrelated. Joins give you every combination valid for the join conditions. Unless you have some relation between phone and address (or synthesize a cumbersome "row number") you cannot really force the result you want. For any client_id you will get N*M result rows (where N is the number of matching phone rows, and M is the number of matching address rows).  _...which is why I say "cumbersome", what results would you expect when M != N?_

Comment: I guess that sample data and expected output would help us find the relevant solution.